# eslint rule to disallow useless lines

Tags: javascript, eslint

Consider the following code:

```
let x = 50;
x -+ 50;
```

The second line is useless because it does nothing. In fact, this line was supposed to be `x -= 50;`

Is there any rule in eslint to spot this kind of line?

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-expressions?

Comment: @jonrsharpe looks right to me maybe this should be an answer

Comment: Yes. It is what I was looking for. But I can't accept a comment.